# CMD: 'C:\Users\Md' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, command-prompt, selenium-ide

I'm new to selenium and currently studying selenium IDE
I'm trying to run selenium side runner by using command prompt but it returns 'C:\Users\Md' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
My project location- "C:\selenium_webdriver\Project2.side"

My command:

[image: 1]

I have tried

- Changing Path variables, rebooting, etc.
- Changing file directory
- Run as administrator

Comment: Did you try - open the command prompt from the directory - 'C:\selenium_webdriver\', then run the command 'selenium-side-runner Project2.side'

Answer (score 0):

It's the spaces in `Md Zin Bin Dekan`. Use `C:\Users\Md~1` or remove the spaces from the directory

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `npm` folder lies under `%AppData%`. If so then copy/move the `npm` folder to a path which has no space in it (`C:\npm` e.g.). Then change the `npm` path within your `PATH` environment variables to the path you chose before.

Close all command-line windows (if any open), open a new window and try your command. If you still run into issues type `path` in the command line und check whether your changes had been saved.